Identification of broken symmetry and unbroken symmetry
Consider a set of scalar fields, denoted as $\phi_i,\,\,i = 1,\cdots,N$ and suppose the Lagrangian preserve some symmetry whose generator denoted as $(T_a)^i_{\,\,j}$ in the representation of $\phi_i$.
$$\phi^i\rightarrow\phi^i + i\epsilon(T_a)^i_{\,\,j}\phi^j + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\tag{1}$$
$$\mathcal{L}[\phi_i] = \frac{1}{2}(\partial^\mu\phi_i(x))^2 - V[\phi_i(x)]\tag{2}$$
Now it is well-known that if the ground state (minimum of potential) doesn't preserve the symmetry, then there would be spontaneous symmetry breaking, however, I'm a little bit confused about the identification of the ground state doesn't preserve the symmetry.
Commonly, if we choose the v.e.v of field to be $\langle\phi\rangle = \phi_0$ (I ignore the idex of the set of scalar fields here), then the definition of broken symmetry and unbroken one are,
$$T_a\langle\phi\rangle \neq 0\tag{3}$$
$$T_a\langle\phi\rangle = 0\tag{4}$$
respectively, and the reason of this definition is because we assume to perturbate our theory around the chosen ground state, and follow from eq(2), the first order of transformation is proportional to $T\phi$.
However, there are contributions from $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$, does this mean the definition of unbroken and broken symmetry is no longer valid if we do non-infinitesimal transformation? Since we would have to consider contributions $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$, then how do we define the broken and unbroken symmetry?

(3) and (4) are necessary signatures of SB or not for the ground state, not definitions. SB is defined as $\exp(i\epsilon T_a)|\Omega\rangle \neq |\Omega\rangle$.

@CosmasZachos See Howard Georgi Weak Interactions eq(2.5.6), I think my (3) and (4) are used as identification of SB.

Your text is mostly interested in small perturbations, fluctuations around the potential minimum, surveying possible quadratic mass terms and null mass matrix directions around the minimum. In your language,
$$\phi^i\rightarrow \phi^{'~i}=(\exp(i\epsilon T_a) \phi)^i  \tag{1},$$
which amounts to preserved symmetry for
$$\langle\phi'\rangle=\exp(i\epsilon T_a) \langle\phi\rangle=\langle\phi \rangle \tag{4'},$$
and broken for
$$\langle\phi'\rangle=\exp(i\epsilon T_a) \langle\phi\rangle\neq\langle\phi \rangle \tag{3'}.$$
For small/infinitesimal ε, this amounts to your infinitesimal conditions entering the perturbation around the minimum, but you may see (4') trivially obtains for the finite transformations, given your (4); and (3') for the SB ones, as it is meant to work for all ε. This is  a generic feature of Lie symmetries around the identity (Lie's 3rd theorem).
